# Untwisting is isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So I have come across the following claim in [this paper by B. Poonen](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/bertini.pdf) (Lemma 2.2): Let $X$ is a smooth quasi-projective scheme over $\mathbb{F}_q$, $P$ a closed point, $\mathfrak{m}$ the ideal sheaf corresponding to $P$ and $Y$ the closed subscheme corresponding to $\mathfrak{m}^2$. The there is an isomorphism
$$H^0(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y(d)) \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} H^0(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y),$$
by untwisting with a suitable coordinate. I don't see how this is an isomorphism as I would expect the left vector space to have a higher dimension than the right. Can anyone give me a hint why this map is indeed a isomorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Y$ is affine with reduction $\operatorname{Spec} k(P)$, so any line bundle on $Y$ is in fact trivial. You can see this by taking $M$ a projective module of rank one and a module map $f:k[Y]\to M$ and showing that $f$ is an isomorphism iff $\overline{f}:k[Y]/\mathfrak{m}\to M/\mathfrak{m}M$ is and identifying $k[Y]/\mathfrak{m}\cong M/\mathfrak{m}M\cong k(P)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don’t think I completely understand. What exactly do you mean by $Y$ having reduction $\operatorname{Spec} k(P)$? Also where do we use that $Y$ corresponds to $\mathfrak{m}^2$?

Comment: Your confusions answer each other: $Y$ is affine and isomorphic to the spectrum of $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}/m_{P}^2$, which is a non-reduced ring (that is, it has nilpotents). The reduction of this scheme is the spectrum of $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}/m_{P}\cong k(P)$, which comes from modding out the nilpotents.